# Turning a CD into a DVD

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

My extra credit assignment is to "turn a CD into a DVD." In other words, I'm supposed to take a CD and change some software stuff on it to fool the computer into thinking it's a DVD, since according to my professor single-layer DVD's are physically the same as CD's, except they can hold more information.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a trick question? I've found no evidence you can do anything like this, and everything I know about how optical media works says you can't. Apparently you can [turn the PLAYER](http://hiddencomputer.blogspot.com/2008/03/turn-cd-drive-into-dvd-drive.html), though. Never tried such a thing, so YMMV.

Comment: A CD does not have any `some software stuff on it` for you to change. Either you have seriously misunderstood your assignment or your *professor* is clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CD is definitely not "physically the same" as a single-layer DVD. However, I've read that if you burn a DVD-compatible file system onto a CD, a few DVD players and most computer DVD player software will interpret it as a DVD.

Videohelp.com calls this non-standard "DVD format on a CD" a [miniDVD or cDVD](http://www.videohelp.com/oldguides/minidvd). However, Wikipedia points out [miniDVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiniDVD_(disambiguation)) is also used to mean an 8-cm DVD disc.

Searching for miniDVD or cDVD might help you find how to properly burn this format if you want to play around with it. Just be careful the results you find are talking about the "DVD format on a CD" and not the 8-cm DVD disc.

For example, here's a videohelp.com [post](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/61896-Burning-mini-DVD-to-CD-R) that suggests you'll need to use DVD authoring software to make a DVD image file (or directory structure), then use a burning program to burn the image (or directory structure in UDF/ISO9660 mode) onto the CD.